front-end is experiencing a 301 issue
1st, The problem occurs when the local front-end project debugs overseas API services, the pre and prod environment is work, they are all in the same k8s cluster;
2nd, There is an issue with the local front-end project connecting to the overseas API service of the pre-release environment, it's not clear why the 301 problem is happening. The scenario is to request an API service deployed in Silicon Valley in the United States in Chinese mainland
works:

401: When we request directly and encounter a 401, the server does not verify the corresponding cookie and reports it.

301: when I add 10 seconds to the token expiration time, the request becomes a 301

